# Get a list of dynamically filtered items inside an ARRAYFORMULA in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to do a pretty simple thing - I have two lists, `Countries` and `Cities`.

Each city has a country as a property in a separate column.

I want to list all the cities for each respective country in a separate column.

I can do that easily with something like that:

```
=FILTER(Cities!$A$1:$A; Cities!$B$1:$B = Countries!$A1)
```

And that works fine for the whole list of countries if I just stretch that formula down.

However, I need that list to be dynamic, so I could use ARRAYFORMULA, kinda like that:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(Cities!$A$1:$A; Cities!$B$1:$B = Countries!$A1:$A))
```

That doesn't work obviously - and neither do OFFSET, CHOOSECOLUMN and even QUERY.

Is there a way to make that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try on-

```
=MAP(TOCOL(Countries!$A1:A,1),LAMBDA(x,TOROW(FILTER(Cities!$A$1:$A; Cities!$B$1:$B =x))))
```

Comment: You, sir, are a genius!

Comment: @Nidere Glad to know it helps.